# Input field is not clickable in mobile view

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div class="form-group row pswrd" style="padding: 0px 10px">
  <div id="email" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <input type="password" class="form-control c_fname" id="c" #pswd name="password" placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" ngModel required>
  </div>
</div>
```

The password input field under Login is not clickable for some reason on Mobile  in this website. http://dev.fudza.com/

Does anyone have an idea of what may be happening here?

Comment: `#loginalign[_ngcontent-c3] {     max-height: 70px; }` is your problem

Comment: I fix your code style. dear @Sreehari, please add a related tag to your post. that's true that your post is related to `html` and `css` but still `angular` is important. I leave an upvote to you, hope it helps you. good luck dear dude.

Answer (score 1):

You have a positioning problem, the:

```
div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12"...
```

With the *remember me* and *forgot password?* is placed over the password input field...

Without its position: relative; you can access the password input field.

Comment: I fix your style of code. just for a better view. I leave an upvote for your answer and I hope you will try to answer more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I saw your [link](http://dev.fudza.com/) on mobile view by using Google chrome dev tools. in Mobile, the below pane of login overlap the password and prevents the click event. see below picture:

[image]

Finally, this is a `CSS` problem, fix the height of **hover div** and your problem will remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, follow these steps:

1. remove `max-height` from `#loginalign` so that `password` field and `remember me` sections will not overlap in small devices.
2. add class `mb-0` to the `password` field so that it will remove unwanted space below the fields.
3. to remove space between `login` button and `Remember me` in small devices, remove `margin-top` from `.login_1` in `@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px)`.